# DB2 DELETE query to return count

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I have very minimal knowledge in writing dynamic queries. As part some implementation I have a need to write a DB2 DELETE query which should be able to delete the rows, as well as it should return the count of rows affected.
So that this query will be put in a DB2 stored procedure, where I have have this count as an OUT parameter.

I was trying as below, which is returning the count but doesn't delete the rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(STUDENT_ID) AS DELETE
  FROM STUDENT
  WHERE STUDENT_LOCATION = 'TNAGAR' 
    AND DATE(JOINING_DATE) < CURRENT DATE - 120 MONTHS;
```

However this can be achieved using two individual queries i.e. one for select and another for delete, but I am looking for one single query to achieve this.

Comment: http://www.mvsforums.com/helpboards/viewtopic.php?t=6566&highlight=sqlerrd

Comment: What Db2 version and platform?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL PL procedures in Db2, you can use the GET DIAGNOSTICS statement to return the number of rows affected by a previous insert/update/delete. See the documentation at this [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005647.html).

Example:

```
declare v_rows_affected integer default 0;
...
DELETE FROM ...
get diagnostics v_rows_affected = row_count ;
```

If you are using a programming language other than SQL PL, with access to the SQLCA, then this information is also present in a part of the [SQLCA](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_descriptionofsqlcafields.html) (specifically `SQLERRD(3)`).